# Is there a way to record every date that a Drop-Down Menu item was last used?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

Essentially I have created a schedule, including a date, an assignee, and a drop-down menu of about 190 different options they could be assigned.

What I want to do is have a record of when each drop-down option has been used, and also which assignee's have used it, perhaps by adding that information to a separate sheet or to the cells at the right of the drop-down menu data.

Is there a way to do that?

EDIT: I don't need the actual date it was selected, just the date/name that is on the schedule

Here's a link to an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ww6gJRgG4gx7odE84TndfqqLBGcC-vMrbxeoDskDBpM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome Kory.  To make it easier for others to help you, please share a sample copy of your sheet - here is a guide on how to share: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en  Also, when you say record, do you meane the date/time of when a dropdown value was used?  I think that might require a script, not just a formula.  But everything else should be possible with formulas.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I don't need the actual date it was selected, just the date/name that is on the schedule

Here's a link to an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ww6gJRgG4gx7odE84TndfqqLBGcC-vMrbxeoDskDBpM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula anywhere on row 2 of your data sheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  QUERY(
    {Main!B2:B,TEXT(Main!A2:A,"m/d/yy") &", "&Main!C2:C&", "&Main!D2:D,Main!A2:A},
    "select Col1, Col2 where Col1 >0 order by Col1,Col3",0))
```

This returns all of the Assignments that have been used, with the other data columns also merged into the format you requested.

But I was uncertain on two points.  Do you prefer to have every Assignment listed (1,2,3,4,5...195,196) like you do in your Data sheet, or is it better just listing the ones that have been used, which is what the formula above does.  Doing the former is even easier, using VLOOKUP perhaps, but might only list the most recent usage of each Assignment.

And two, you asked for a record of each unique time an Assignment is used, if possible, otherwise just the latest.  I've listed each unique time, each on its own row.  If you want some other format, please create a few more data samples, and show how the result should then look on the Data tab.

In my sample below, the formula is in H2, and I had five rows of assignments, using 1 (twice), 3 (twice), and 46.

### Detailed explanation

The formula is basically a query, but the data is restructured into a virtual array first, to get the desired format of the output.  From the Main tab, the Assignments, column B, are used, and Columns A, C, and D are joined together, with column A forced to a text format first, from a numeric/date value.  Column B, the dates, is used again, to permit sorting in date sequence, within assignment sequence.

Only rows in Main with an Assignment (in column B, but Col1 in our virtual array) are selected.  Lastly, the ARRAYFORMULA is required to merge each row of the three data columns, A, C, and D, using the "&" connector.

[image]